# Bokeh: How to set a single-index labeled legend for a bar plot with a double-indexed Pandas grouped Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

Following the [guidelines for categorical data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.2.0/docs/user_guide/categorical.html?highlight=handling%20categorical%20data) of Bokeh, I grouped with two columns the following `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    weekday=['Monday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday'],
    daytime=['morning', 'evening', 'night', 'afternoon', 'afternoon', 'morning', 'night'],
    value=[12,13,15,5,14,12,11]
))
groupby_datetime = df.groupby(['weekday', 'daytime'], as_index=True)
```

I set a colormap:

```py
daytime_cmap = factor_cmap('weekday_daytime', palette=['orange','darkviolet','yellow','darkblue'],
                           factors=sorted(df.daytime.unique()), start=1)
```

and plotted an histogram (weekdays are not in order, working on that):

```py
p = figure(x_range=groupby_datetime)
p.vbar(x='weekday_daytime', top='value_mean', width=0.9, line_color=None, source=groupby_datetime,
      fill_color=daytime_cmap, legend_field='weekday_daytime')

#drop the innermost labels https://stackoverflow.com/q/48190381/5599687
p.xaxis.formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format='')

show(p)
```

The result is the following, as expected.

[image]

My question is: **how can I turn this legend to a single-index one?** I would like to have just four colours, one for each time of the day? The day of the week should be labeled just on the axis.

Comment: You mean for example to show monday and then the two colors? Or to have just one color for monday? Please clarify your expected output.

Comment: I would like to have four colours, one for each time of the day; the day of the week should be labeled only on the axis.